# Android radiobutton indicator hide

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I want to hide radio button indicator, which shows that radio button is checked or unchecked. I just want to show its text only. And change text color of radio button which is selected in radio group and other radio buttons text will same.

Here is my onCheckedChanged code.

```
        @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked){
            itemView.removeAllViews();

            for (Subjects subjects : item.subjects) {

                View iv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandablelistview_item, itemView, false);
                TextView itemName = (TextView) iv.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                itemName.setText(subjects.name + " " + subjects.marks);

                itemView.addView(iv);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could use a button instead, set a click listener and default colour and change colour on every click

Comment: Or a TextView, with the `clickable` attribute set to **true**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide RadioButton indicator with:
    android:button="@null"
xml attribute to RadioButton item.

Then create your own selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/..."/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/..."/>
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/..."/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

if you want change text background and use it in android:background RadioButton attribute. Otherwise set 
android:background="@android:color/transparent"

And color of text you can change with color selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_pressed="true
          android:color="@color/..."/>
      <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="@color/..."/>
      <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:color="@color/..."/>
      <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:color="@color/..."/>
      <item android:color="@color/..."/>
 </selector>
```

and insert it to 
android:textColor="@color/..."
attribute.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I am using the selector on drawableRight. I used the first selector suggested above.
<code>
`<RadioButton   <br/>
                        style="@style/RadioTextStyle"  <br/>
                        android:button="@null"  <br/>
                      android:drawableRight="@drawable/radio_selector">`  <br/>
</code>